# SQL Query breaking for some reason

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

Please consider the following Image:

[image]

When I ran the following query in coldfusion:

```
<cfquery datasource="mydb" name="qCoulmnInsert">
INSERT INTO 
simplexresults.contactresults_email_account_summary_devices 
(open_desktop_int,
open_other_int,
open_phone_int,
open_tablet_int,
open_webmail_int,  
<!--- FOR Unique Open --->
unique_webMail_int,
unique_tablet_int,
unique_other_int,
unique_phone_int,
unique_desktop_int,
<!--- FOR DATES --->
startdate_dt,
enddate_dt,
date_dt)

VALUES
<!--- loop through your array --->
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(cfData)#" index="i">
(
<cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
<cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].open.Desktop#">
<cfelse>
NULL
</cfif> ,
<cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
<cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].open.Other#">
<cfelse>
NULL
</cfif> ,


<cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
<cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].open.Phone#">
<cfelse>
NULL
</cfif> ,

  and so on and so forth ...
                   ....

</cfquery>
```

I get the following error:

```
 Element OPEN.DESKTOP is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.

The error occurred in C:\myfile.cfm: line 55

53 :              (
54 :               <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
55 :                 <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].open.Desktop#">
56 :               <cfelse>
57 :                 NULL
```

I know it's not defined for some of the structures as shown in the image below, but I have included "NULL" in my `<cfelse>` statement to handle those cases. Am I doing something wrong here? Please advise.

However the query runs fine for the date range where OPEN'S are defined.

**Correct Way:**

```
<cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
                <cfif  structKeyExists(cfData[i].open,"Desktop")>
                <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Desktop"]#">
                <cfelse>
                 NULL
                </cfif>
              <cfelse>
                NULL

              </cfif> ,
```

Comment: I don't know how to do this in coldfusion, but you should print out the final query that is being generated and let us have a look at it.

Comment: Damien, it's erroring out before the SQL is generated. It's a ColdFusion error, not a SQL error.

Comment: I have had discussion related with such query before if that helps :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470019/accessing-complex-structure-in-coldfusion#comment33061029_21470019

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You qualify that "open" is available in your if statement, but "Desktop" is not always available and is not wrapped in a qualifying statement. If other words, "Desktop" is not always a key, but your loop always looks for it as long as the "open" key is defined.

Comment: But I have <cfelse> condition as well. why it isn't helping? Should I consider using 0 value instead of NULL ?

Comment: @user3239126: the problem is not in the cfelse. The error message you are getting indicates that "DESKTOP" is not an element in the structure. (You could do a cfdump of the structure, immediately prior to the line that's throwing the error.) As Chris Tierney  pointed out in his answer, you are testing whether "OPEN" is an element, but you are _not_ testing whether "DESKTOP" is an element of the "OPEN" structure before you reference it.

Comment: Yep. Just because the *parent* key ie `open` exists, does not mean the child keys ie `desktop`, `open` will exist as well (`desktop`, `open`). You *must* test them both - separately. First test the parent key `structKeyExists(struct, "parentKeyName")`, then the child key `structKeyExists(struct.parentKeyName, "childKeyName")`.

Comment: Thansk Leigh and other guys. It worked. I have updated myquestion with my answer. Is there a way to use something better than using NULL just like I am using? Just wondering.

Comment: If you want to insert `null` for missing values, it is not really a matter of better or worse. Though you could simplify the code by combining the two structKeyExist calls into a single `cfif`.

Comment: I believe in order to keep the query execution plan cached, you'll want to do a <cfqueryparam type="cf_sql_integer" null="true"> instead of just "NULL" as your value. This is due to the fact the "NULL" is not a static value.

Comment: Cool. Is it a good idea to insert 0 instead of Null so that if for some reason, SUM function is applied on a column, it won't create any problem in adding all the integer values without any "NULL" ?

Comment: It really all depends upon your plan. Many times NULL is used to say the data just doesn't exist, when 0 says it's actually 0. Now I have heard in the past to never use NULL because it will slow down lookups, but I've never really looked into it.