# getting same error on different circumstances

Tags: coldfusion

Please consider the code below:

I am getting JSON data based on the date range I am specifying on the url & I am   deserializing it as folows:

```
<cfhttp url="#urladdress#" method="GET" resolveurl="Yes" throwonerror="Yes">

 <cfset cfData=DeserializeJSON(CFHTTP.FileContent)> 

<cfset arraylen = ArrayLen(cfdata)>
```

I am grabbing the data and inserting into MySQL database as follows:

```
<cfquery datasource="XX.X.XX.XXX" name="qCoulmnInsert">
    INSERT INTO Mytable
     (aol_int,
     android_Phone_int,
     androidTablet_int,
     apple_mail_int,
     blackberry_int,
     Eudora_int,
     gMail_int,
     Hotmail_int,
     lotus_notes_int,
     other_int,
     other_webmail_int,
     Outlook_int,
     Postbox_int,
     sparrow_int,
     thunderbird_int,
     windowsLiveMail_int,
     yahoo_int,
     iPad_int,
     iphone_int,
     iPod_int,
    <!--- FOR DATES --->
     startdate_dt,
     enddate_dt,
     date_dt)

   VALUES
     <!--- loop through your array --->
     <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(cfData)#" index="i">
     ( <!--- 1 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["aol"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>,

     <!--- 2 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Android Phone"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>,

     <!--- 3 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Android Tablet"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>,

     <!--- 4 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Apple Mail"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>,

     <!--- 5 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Blackberry"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>,

     <!--- 6 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Eudora"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>,

     <!--- 7 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["gmail"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>,

     <!--- 8 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["hotmail"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>,

     <!--- 9 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Lotus Notes"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>, 

     <!--- 10 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Other"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif> ,

     <!--- 11 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Other Webmail"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>,

     <!--- 12 ---> 
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Outlook"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif> ,

     <!--- 13 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Postbox"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif> ,

     <!--- 14 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Thunderbird"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif> ,

     <!--- 15 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Sparrow"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif> ,

     <!--- 16 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Windows Live Mail"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif> ,

     <!--- 17 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Yahoo"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif> ,

     <!--- 18 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["iPad"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif> ,

     <!--- 19 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["iPhone"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif> ,

     <!--- 20 --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["iPod"]#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif> ,

  <!--- FOR DATES --->
     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "startdate_dt")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#cfData[i].startdate_dt#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>, 

     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "enddate_dt")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#cfData[i].enddate_dt#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif>,

     <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "date")>
     <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#cfData[i].date#">
     <cfelse>
     NULL
     </cfif> 

    )

     <cfif i neq arrayLen(cfData)>,</cfif>
     </cfloop>
    </cfquery>
```

Problem I am facing:

When the JSON data does not has "Lotus Notes" in it, I get an error "Element Lotus Notes is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression. "

an points to the line `<cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Lotus Notes"]#">`

When it has Lotus Notes in the JSON , it picks up some other element and I got the error "Element Eudora is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression. "
and points to the line `<cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i]["open"]["Eudora"]#">` in above code

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ajby/) is the sample JSON with Lotus Notes on date Jan 01

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PLxzA/) it is without Lotus Notes (from Jan 02) field where I get Eudora error

I don't understand where I am wrong. Please advise

Comment: Check the query formed after looping. Looks like the inserted columns and the number of values might not be matching.

Comment: As an aside, this sounds a lot like a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841437/sql-query-breaking-for-some-reason#comment33063126_21841578)... As mentioned on that thread, the `cfif` logic is flawed. Just because the parent key "open" exists, is no guarantee the individual child keys "Eudora", ... will always exist. It is not enough to just test the parent key.You must test them BOTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't check before you reference.  This is how I'd write it.

```
 <!--- 1 --->
 <cfset data = cfData[i]>
 <cfset isVarDefined = isDefined("variables.data.open.aol")>
 <cfset value = isVarDefined ? data.open.aol : "">
 <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#value#" null="#!isVarDefined#">

 <!--- 2 --->
 <!--- very similar to the code above... --->
```

Comment: IsDefined is discouraged because it is less precise, and more prone to wrong results, than the alternatives. Though in this specific case, a better reason is .. it does not actually work with array notation ;-)

Comment: Yep. The input string has to be a valid "variable name", otherwise isDefined complains.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single check for whether `cfData[i].Open` exists - if it doesn't all those ints are going to be null, so just output 20 nulls. (Or perhaps don't bother with the insert at all - depends what's going on here).

Also, you don't need explicit hard-coded logic for every single one - just use a loop and check the existence inside the loop with a single piece of code - i.e:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(cfData[i],'open')>

    <cfloop index="Key" array=#['aol','Android Phone','Android Tablet','etc']# >

        ,
        <cfif StructKeyExists( cfData[i].open , Key ) >
            <cfqueryparam value=#cfData[i].open[Key]# cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
        <cfelse>
            <cfqueryparam value="" null=true />
        </cfif>

    </cfloop>

<cfelse>

    #RepeatString( ',null' , 20 )#

</cfif>
```